# T-SQL Dynamic date range in WHERE clause (Last fiscal year + year to date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I'm using the following WHERE clause to only load records from the last fiscal year plus a year to date.

Running without the `WHERE clause`, it takes 30seconds for 1mil records. With the WHERE clause, I had to stop it after 2hours.

Can you please share your thoughts

```
WHERE 
    ([schema].[table].[DATE] >= DATEADD
        (yy, - 1, DATEADD
            (MONTH,(MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1) / 6 * 12 - 6,
             CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Put calculation in a variable and compare the date to that. i.e. `declare @d datetime = DATEADD
        (yy, - 1, DATEADD
            (MONTH,(MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1) / 6 * 12 - 6,
             CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
            )`   ... `WHERE 
    ([schema].[table].[DATE] >= @d`

Comment: Even though that didn't solve my issue, I made that change anyway. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean on "a year to date"? Is this last FY up to the current date? So if your FY started on OCT 1 it would be OCT1 2014 - TODAY?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @PastFiscalYear Date

    Set @PastFiscalYear= DATEADD(yy, - 1, DATEADD(MONTH,(MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1) / 6 * 12 - 6,CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)))

    WHERE 
        ([schema].[table].[DATE] >= @PastFiscalYear )
```

Can you try this

Comment: :To format ,highlight the code and click on code sample

Comment: Unfortunately it does not make much of a difference. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'll look at indexes tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This will bring back data since the previous fiscal year start date. Just change the -3 to what ever your FY offset is. -3 is for October.

```
[schema].[table].[DATE] >= DATEADD(mm,-3,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())), 0))
```